# How would I show my own public and private IP on a page?

Tags: html

I want to create an extra page that shows me the website server's public and private IP on my page for debuugging. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please give us some more details about what you already tried, if you are using Javascript or some other web technology/framework,...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use PHP.

I have no idea about the private IP but, for your public IPv4, use this:

```
<?php 
// Declaring a variable to hold the IP
// address getHostName() gets the name 
// of the local machine getHostByName() 
// gets the corresponding IP 
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName()); 
  
// Displaying the address  
echo $localIP; 
  
?>
```

Comment: I think I misworded what I wanted: I need my public ip. Could you please make a followup answer?